# How do I add String elements from a text file into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, arrays

The text file contains numbers separated by commas (ex. 458.58, 1598.45...).

I want to add an entire line from the text file into an ArrayList.

Here is my code so far:

```
// to calculate final output
ArrayList<String> weeklySales = new ArrayList<String>(7);

// week 1 sales
while(file.hasNext()) {
    weeklySales.add(file.nextLine());
    System.out.println("I ran!");
}

System.out.println(weeklySales);
```

EDIT: Sorry my question wasn't clear. My question is after running this code, it adds ALL the elements of the ENTIRE text file into my array, BUT I need to only add 1 LINE to its own individual ArrayList. So in total I will have as many array lists as there are lines of text in the file.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: Edolsa, if you found the solution, you may as well mark it as the 'answer'

Comment: It won't let me, I have to wait 2 hours it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. I realized that the most convenient method for working with individual lines and separating individual numbers from the text file was using StringTokenizer. Here is the fully working code, all you will need is the text file, which is named 'SalesData.txt' and mine includes the following 3 lines:

1245.67,1490.07,1679.87,2371.46,1783.92,1461.99,2059.77
2541.36,2965.88,1965.32,1845.23,7021.11,9652.74,1469.36
2513.45,1963.22,1568.35,1966.35,1893.25,1025.36,1128.36

This program outputs the following:
-Total sales for each week
-Daily average for each week
-Total sales of all the weeks
-Average weekly total
-The week with the highest sales
-The week with the lowest sales

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

// create file object
File salesData = new File("SalesData.txt");

// open file
Scanner file  = new Scanner(salesData);

// declare 2 dimensional array 
double[][] weeklySales = new double[3][7];

// loop to initialize token
int row = 0;
while(file.hasNext()) {
// initialize token
String line = file.nextLine();
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

// fill columns and rows
int col = 0;
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        // convert to double and assign to token
    weeklySales[row][col] = Double.parseDouble(tokens.nextToken());
    // move up 1 column
    col++;
    }
// move down 1 row
row++;
}

// calculate weekly sales
double week1Sales = 0, week2Sales = 0, week3Sales = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        double daily = weeklySales[i][j];
        if(i == 0)
            week1Sales += daily;
        else if(i == 1)
            week2Sales += daily;
        else if(i == 2)
            week3Sales += daily;
    }
}
// week 1 sales
System.out.println("Week 1 total sales: $" +formatter.format(week1Sales));
// week 2 sales
System.out.println("Week 1 total sales: $" +formatter.format(week2Sales));
// week 3 sales
System.out.println("Week 1 total sales: $" +formatter.format(week3Sales));

// average daily for week 1
System.out.println("Daily average for week 1: $" +formatter.format(week1Sales / 7));

// average daily for week 2
System.out.println("Daily average for week 2: $" +formatter.format(week2Sales / 7));

// average daily for week 3
System.out.println("Daily average for week 3: $" +formatter.format(week3Sales / 7));

// total for all weeks
double weeklyTotal = week1Sales + week2Sales + week3Sales;

System.out.println("Total sales of all the weeks: $" +formatter.format(weeklyTotal));

// average weekly sales
System.out.println("Average weekly total: $" + formatter.format(weeklyTotal / 3));

// week number with highest sales
if(week1Sales > week2Sales)
    if(week1Sales > week3Sales)
        System.out.println("The week with the highest sales is week 1.");
    else
        System.out.println("The week with the highest sales is week 3.");
else if(week2Sales > week3Sales)
    if(week2Sales > week1Sales)
        System.out.println("The week with the highest sales is week 2.");
    else
        System.out.println("The week with the highest sales is week 1.");
else
    System.out.println("The week with the highest sales is week 3.");

// week number with the lowest
if(!(week1Sales > week2Sales))
    if(!(week1Sales > week3Sales))
        System.out.println("The week with the lowest sales is week 1.");
    else
        System.out.println("The week with the lowest sales is week 3.");
else if(!(week2Sales > week3Sales))
    if(!(week2Sales > week1Sales))
        System.out.println("The week with the lowest sales is week 2.");
    else
        System.out.println("The week with the lowest sales is week 1.");
else
    System.out.println("The week with the lowest sales is week 3.");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code, you can use :

```
String line = "458.58, 1598.45";
String array[] = line.split(", ");
```

Changing from String to double is possible by this way :

```
Double.valueOf(array[i]);
```

Changing array into list can be done with this :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the code, this seems to work but the problem is you showed how to add it to an Array, but I want to add the elements to an ArrayList.

Comment: Changing array into list added.